# Create a "Select All" option in a Choice column (List)

Tags: list

I have a list that has all 50 states and the requirements from the user are requesting a "Select All" option that will check off all 50 states. I have been searching and have found several instances of code but I can't get any of them to work. Can anyone out there help me figure out what code will Select All of the states? Or is there an option that doesn't require code (that would be preferred). Thanks!

Comment: What version of Sharepoint are you using? Such function is not possible with out of the box functionality other then creating a new option called ALL but that may affect business logic if you have some wf running on that list.

Comment: As Marek asked, what version? How should a user select all choices? By a button?